# Vary position of the formatting buttons at the bottom if the user is on a tablet?

Tags: bug, user-experience

Above the box I'm currently typing in are formatting buttons for bold, italic, quote, code etc. I frequently run into a nuisance on my iPad whereby I select some text that I wish to make Bold (for example), and the ipad floats a selection of black buttons inviting me to Cut/Copy/Paste/Replace etc my selection - many times these floating buttons obscure the formatting controls on SO

The only workaround I've found is to add sufficient newlines to put my text down, then select it and format it, then remove the newlines again. Alternatively I can arrange the scrolling of the text box so my selection will be at the bottom but this isn't always easy if a large amount is to be selected

Could the buttons be moved to below the text area for iPad (and other tablets that float a command list above a selection) ?

To be clear, this is the desktop version of the site as viewed in the iPad safari browser

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: This is not a bug, since SO doesn't support using the desktop version on a mobile device.

Comment: Does it offer a way to switch to mobile site on tablet? On an iphone, the mobile site loads by default. On a tablet, desktop site loads by default. I'd taken that as the base assumption that desktop site mode is the intended mode for tablets?